# How to notate altered diatonic scales (in this case Mixolydian ♭6)?

Tags: notation, scales, key-signatures

If I am notating a piece that's in [mostly] a C Mixolydian ♭6 scale (B♭ and A♭), what approach to notation would be most easily read?

1. Notate everything in a non-standard key signature, B♭, E♮, and  A♭.
2. Notate as C major (no ♯ or ♭ in the key signature), and add B♭ and  A♭ accidentals.
3. Notate as C minor (B♭ E♭  A♭ in the key signature) and notate E♮ as an accidental.
4. Notate as C Mixolydian (B♭) in the key signature, and A♭ as an accidental.
5. Since it is a mode of F jazz minor, Notate as F minor (B♭ E♭ A♭ D♭) with D♮ and E♮ accidentals.

I am leaning toward option 2. or 4. above, since the the key is clearly C, E♮ defines the major quality, which seems more important than the 6th and 7th degrees.  The nonstandard signature might be confusing.

Are there some general principles to guide the decision for altered scales in general (e.g. Dorian ♭2)?

Comment: Duplicate? [Key signature for writing in modes other than major and minor](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/930/key-signature-for-writing-in-modes-other-than-major-and-minor)